# builtins.TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' from scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am completely thrown for a loop with this error. This seems to happen whenever I try to run my spider through the scraping hub python api wrapper. Any idea why scrapy is throwing this error? It seems that this error is being generated from within one of Scrapy's built in function?

Code that generated this error:

```
from scrapinghub import ScrapinghubClient


url = 'https://www.amazon.ca/Portable-Charger-Anker-PowerCore-20100mAh/dp/B00X5RV14Y?ref_=Oct_DLandingS_D_2f0fdbee_60&smid=AREE309N4XPXI'
email='testuser@mail.com'
uuid='testuuid123'  

client = ScrapinghubClient(api_key)

project = client.get_project(575768)

job = project.jobs.run(
    'listings_spider',
    job_args={
    'uuid':uuid,
    'user_email':email,
    'URL':url}
    )
```

Top half of my spider:

```
r = redis.Redis(
    host=os.environ.get('REDIS_HOST'), 
    password=os.environ.get('REDIS_PASS'), 
    port=os.environ.get('REDIS_PORT'), 
    db=0)

class ListingsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    
    def __init__(self, user_email, URL, uuid, optional_product_name=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user_email = user_email
        # print(f"DEBUG: {self.user_email}")

        # User input
        self.optional_product_name = optional_product_name
        self.URL = 'https://www.amazon.ca/Portable-Charger-Anker-PowerCore-20100mAh/dp/B00X5RV14Y?ref_=Oct_DLandingS_D_2f0fdbee_60&smid=AREE309N4XPXI'
        self.uuid = uuid

    name = "listings_spider"
    # user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:94.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/94.0'
    # user_agent = None
    

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            self.URL, 
            callback=self.parse)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1185, in get_connection
    connection = self._available_connections.pop()
IndexError: pop from empty list

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 89, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 157, in maybeDeferred_coro
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/app/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/spiderstate.py", line 29, in spider_closed
    pickle.dump(spider.state, f, protocol=4)
AttributeError: 'ListingsSpider' object has no attribute 'state'
```

Comment: I think the problem is redis and not scrapy, try to comment some lines and see where's the problem.